# UMVUE- geometric distribution where $X$ is the number of failures preceding the first success

Tags: self-study, estimation, negative-binomial-distribution, geometric-distribution, umvue

$X_1, \dots, X_n$ iis geometric: $P(X=x) = (1-p)^{x}p$, $x=0,1,2, \dots$

My Attempt:

$T=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is a sufficient statistic

$W= \begin{cases}1 & X_1= 0,\\ 0 & X_1\neq 0\end{cases}$
W is an unbiased estimator of $p$

To find UMVUE,
\begin{align}
E[W|T=t] &= \frac{P(X_1 = 0, T=t)}{P(T=t)}\\[5pt]
         &= \frac{P(X_1 = 0)P(X_1+\cdots +X_n=t)}{P(T=t)}\\[5pt]
         \end{align}
Can somebody please help me expand this step. It's confusing whether I should use $t-1$ or $t-2$ in the combination part of negative binomial pdf.

Comment: can you please explain me how could you get this result? 1/(1+∑Xi/n−1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $X_j$ is the number of failures preceding the first success for each $j$, $T=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n X_j$ is the number of failures before the $n$th success. Therefore pmf of $T$ is

$$P(T=t)=\binom{n+t-1}{t}\theta^n(1-\theta)^{t}\,\mathbf1_{t\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}}$$

Now,

\begin{align}
E\left[W\mid T=t\right]&=\frac{P\left[X_1=0,\sum\limits_{i=2}^n X_i=t\right]}{P(T=t)}
\\&=\frac{P(X_1=0)P\left[\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1} X_j=t\right]}{P(T=t)}\qquad,\,\small j=i-1
\end{align}

So the '$t$' remains as it is; it is a matter of '$n$' and '$n-1$' in the pmf of negative binomial.

Comment: Is the answer, $\frac{1}{1+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n-1}}$

Comment: That is what I get, yes.

Comment: I also tried solving this question using the fact that geometric distribution belongs to exponential family and therefore $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is complete sufficient. Taking \begin{align}E(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) &=  \frac{n(1-p)}{p} \end{align} from this I got the umvue of $p$ as $\frac{1}{X\bar+1}$. Is this method wrong?

Comment: That looks like a 'method of moment' estimator, found by equating sample mean with population mean. Do you think UMVUE is the same?

Comment: By Lehmann Scheffe theorem, can't UMVUE be obtained from the mean of a complete and sufficient statistic?

Comment: @user46697 You do not know what function of the complete sufficient statistic would yield an unbiased estimator of $p$ beforehand. So at best, you cant start from $E(g(T))=p$ for some function $g$ of $T=\sum X_i$ and try solving for $g$.

Comment: This is what you get from your last comment: $E(T)=\frac{n(1-p)}{p}\implies p=\frac{1}{E(\overline X)+1}$. Does this help in any way? Did you get an unbiased estimator of $p$ based on a complete sufficient statistic?

Comment: In case of $N(\theta,\sigma^{2})$, isn't it true that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is complete sufficient and therefore taking, $E(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)$ = $n\bar X$ thus giving $\bar X$ as UMVUE of $\theta$.?

Comment: Since $E(\bar X)=\theta$ and $\bar X$ is a function of complete sufficient statistic, it is the UMVUE of $\theta$. So? (Use `\bar X` for $\bar X$.)

Comment: In general, $E\left(\frac{1}{\overline X+1}\right)\ne \frac{1}{E(\overline X)+1}$, if that's what you were thinking.

Comment: At the beginning of the answer, shouldn't $W$ be $1$ when $X_1=1$ and $0$ otherwise? It seems the way that it currently is, $W$ is an unbiased estimator of $1-p$ and not $p$, correct?

Comment: @ZeroPancakes No, $E(W)=P(X_1=0)=p$.